# Disable all user accounts?

Tags: accounts, users

I'm not sure all accounts are disabled on my computer, including samba-guest, and I need to disable all accounts except the one I'm using. How can I disable them all?

Comment: So, you want to prevent all users from logging in (local and remote) except for yourself? Service(s): just Samba? Do you have other services like SSH enabled?

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I disabled SSH and yes i need to prevent all users local and remote except my self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set accounts to use /bin/false to prevent login.

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/false <account>
```

So, for user "baduser", use `sudo usermod -s /bin/false baduser` .

You can also edit the password file directly, using a command like `vipw` . 
The resulting line should look something like this:

```
jgb:x:1003:1003:,,,:/home/jgb:/bin/false
```

To be even more secure, you can set allowed users in ssh via `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` .
You would add a line like this:

```
AllowUsers user1 user2 user3
```

Comment: You should not ever allow root login, without very specific reason to do that.

Comment: @olli  -- In this case there's no reason for root in the example, so I've changed it.   Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

[`/etc/nologin`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/nologin.5.html) ?

Comment: could you be more specific please

Comment: "nologin - prevent non-root users from logging into the system". This will not work for regular users.

Comment: Click on the link to see the man: i think you should do both: 1) create /etc/nologin 2) modify SSH just like jgbelacqua said.

Answer (score 0):

should it be permanent oder only for a small time period?

you can disable an account by adding an asterisk in front of the passwords in /etc/password and /etc/shadow or simply backup and delete (same for /etc/samba/smbpasswd depending on your samba config, otherwise you could try to only map your username to the samba an leave the others

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing the PAM configuration files.

e.g. add this to the top of your `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth [default=1 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid ne 0
auth pam_succeed_if.so quiet user != youruser
```

I haven't tested this, so please check it and test it first.

But it's probably easier to just make sure only you (and probably `root`) belong to the `wheel` group, then add this to `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth     required       pam_wheel.so
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo passwd -l USERNAME
```

locked

```
sudo passwd -u USERNAME
```

unlocked